# How do I search the 'Startup' folder in Windows and delete files I don't want?

Tags: python, python-3.x, delete-file

Basically, what I'm trying to do is make a program that once run, saves a copy of itself to the Windows 'Startup' folder.

My friend however has made some sort of 'antivirus' (it's not that great) that checks 'Startup' - when Windows starts up - for any files with the extension `.py` or `.pyw`.

I'm trying to make a section of my program that does the same sort of thing, only it's supposed to delete *his* file before it has time to delete mine.

The program I'm editing is not originally mine, therefore I don't really understand a lot of it, but I have an alright knowledge about Python.  I've tried this in the place I think it's supposed to go, but I get an error:

```
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/%s/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/"):
    if file.endswith(".pyw") or file.endswith(".py"):
        os.remove(file)
```

This is the error I get when I have a file (`Test.py`) in the 'Startup' folder:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Test.py'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You're just passing the file name without the path to `os.remove`, so it tries to delete a file with the name "test.py" in your current working directory. You need to either pass the full file name to `os.remove` or change your working directory.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unaware or the name of the file, hence that I'm trying to destroy anything with a Python-related extension ('.pyw', '.py').

Comment: You already have the file name in the file variable. Just add the path to that and you have the full file name.

Comment: OK!  It worked;  thanks.  I guess I was being a bit stupid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `os.remove(file)` to `os.remove("C:/Users/%s/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/" + file`